# How can I set the endpoint of a VPN Native Plugin in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, vpn

I want to create a VPN app in UWP and I have the following code:

```
var profile = new VpnNativeProfile();

profile.AlwaysOn = true;
profile.NativeProtocolType = VpnNativeProtocolType.IpsecIkev2;
profile.ProfileName = "My Profile";
profile.RememberCredentials = true;
profile.RequireVpnClientAppUI = true;

var agent = new VpnManagementAgent();

agent.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(profile, new PasswordCredential
{
      UserName = "test_username",
      Password = "test_password"
};
```

My problem is: **how** do I set the endpoint (the VPN server IP address) for this VPN connection that I'm trying to create?

I don't see any property that specifies the endpoint of the VPN server that I want to connect to. Also, I haven't found any tutorial on this topic.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I set the endpoint (the VPN server IP address) for this VPN connection that I'm trying to create?

There is the `Routes` property in the `VpnNativeProfile` class. And it is the list of `VpnRoute`. You could make a new [`VpnRoute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn.vpnroute) with specified IP address and add it to `Routes` like the following:

```
profile.Routes.Add(new VpnRoute(new Windows.Networking.HostName("address"), 128));
```

Please note that to use this API, you must specify the [`networkingVpnProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn) capability in your application manifest.

```
<rescap:Capability Name="networkingVpnProvider" />
```

Comment: Scavenger: Sorry for the delay. 
Nico Zhu - MSFT: It doesn't work by updating the Routes. Have you made an app that works that way?

Comment: I even asked this question on Microsoft Forums and they answered me that they simply don't have time to build samples and they redirected me to their Professional Support that costs 500$ per incident. Simply amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the endpoint (Server address) this way

```
profile.Servers.Add("ServerIpOrDomain");
```

Comment: Have you done an app similar to the one that I want to build and it worked by placing the IP in the Servers variable? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes it does work for me, the new vpn connection is added and the server address is also correct. But mycurrent problem is, that i can not set a PSK with the vpn API and the username on connect is not correct (the API adds something like "r\" at the beginning of the username...i'm using the latest non insider Windows 10 with the current VS2017 Community version.

Comment: Really? Can you please send me the code that creates you the VPN connection? Maybe we can work together to build a working example. Thank you!

Comment: That sounds good, i think it would be helpful to others, if we can make some sample Code that works. I have another queston on stack about my problem on how to set the PSK, there i have wrote my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280840/uwp-create-vpn-connection