# UWP create VPN connection

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, vpn

Currently I'm trying to figure out, how to add a VPN profile and connect to it from my universal app. I can connect to existing VPN connections with the `Windows.Networking.Vpn` namespace. I can also add a profile, but can not find a way to set all the required information (PSK for example). There is no documentation about this namespace in the MS docs. I also saw that there are two different profile namespaces available: `VpnNativeProfile` and `VpnPlugInProfile`. What is the difference between them? Currently I'm not at home, so I can't provide my current code, but it would be very helpful if someone can give me some hints. Is there a documentation available somewhere else?

Edit 1//
Here is my sample Code

Creating a profile

```
VpnManagementAgent mgr = new VpnManagementAgent();

VpnNativeProfile profile = new VpnNativeProfile()
{
    AlwaysOn = false,
    NativeProtocolType = VpnNativeProtocolType.L2tp,
    ProfileName = "MyConnection",
    RememberCredentials = true,
    RequireVpnClientAppUI = true,
    RoutingPolicyType = VpnRoutingPolicyType.SplitRouting,
    TunnelAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.PresharedKey,
    UserAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Mschapv2,
};

profile.Servers.Add("vpn.example.com");

VpnManagementErrorStatus profileStatus = await mgr.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);
```

Connecting to the VPN

```
PasswordCredential credentials = new PasswordCredential
{
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
};

VpnManagementErrorStatus connectStatus = await mgr.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(profile, credentials);
```

This works, but i don't know where or how to set  the PSK.

Comment: The `win-universal-app` tag should be used in combination with the used OS (Windows 8.1 or Windows 10).

Comment: Edited the question with sample code.

Comment: I run your code and it doesn't create a new connection on my side. I don't see anything in Connections (in Windows 10). Basically this Native Profile allows you to connect only your UWP app to the VPN? Or it allows you to route the entire traffic from your entire machine through the VPN?

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault, you have to set "RequireVpnClientAppUI = true"
in order to see the connection. No, it should allow all traffic route over the VPN, but you can also use Split-Tunneling with the "RoutingPolicyType" setting.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. On my side, the VpnManagementErrorStatus is set to "Other" when I try to connect. Do you get the same error?

Comment: Can you connect to it from the Windows settings?

Comment: No, I currently don't use real data for connection (meaning endpoint and credentials) because I just wanted to see if it creates the VPN interface. Apparently it only creates the interface when I connect successfully to the VPN, right? So basically the method **ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync** creates the connection, right?

Comment: No, the profile is created by calling "AddProfileFromObjectAsync". I have updated my code above, sorry i forgot this to add here. So the creation of the profile works, but we can not set enough parameters (in my case the PSK).

Comment: @andy  i have started working on vpn. but i am not able to use VpnManagmentAgent class.
please let me know how to include this class in our c sharp project

Comment: @MuhammadTufail, you can use it like in my sample code above. But i couldn't find any way to use my PSK (PreSharedKey)...

Comment: I didn't find the vpnManagementAgent how to include the VpnManagementAgent and vpnNativeProfile

Comment: You have to add the `Windows.Networking.Vpn` namespace for accessing it.

Comment: how to add this namespace can you please guide me.

Comment: you have to add the using directive at the top of your page on which you want to use the class (there are already other using directives). So just add `using Windows.Networking.Vpn;`

Comment: I add the namespace like this before but it showing me the error 
"the type or namespace 'Windows' could not be found (you are missing using directive or an assembly reference)"

Comment: Which version(s) of uwp does your project use?

Comment: Basically i am new in c Sharp and i want to create VPN for windows...

Comment: Basically i am new in c Sharp and i want to create VPN for windows...
I am using windows 10..i am facing issue in including the Windows.Networking.Vpn..
i am using latest UWP

Comment: So you created a new Windows Universal (Blank) app inside Visual Studio?

Comment: yes exactly i create new project in visual studio and now i want to access Windows.Networking.Vpn namepsace classes

Comment: That's weird. Which target and min. version did you select, when you created your project? Are all nuget packages updated?

Comment: target version 1903 (10.0; Build 18362)
Minimum version 1809 (10.0;Build 17763)

Comment: @andy thanks now i am able to access Windows.Networking.Vpn

Comment: @andy i use your code to connect vpn using username password but vpn is not connecting it when i print the profile status or connection status they print the error 
 'other '

Comment: @andy when i connect vpn from window setting then vpn connect successfully but whne i try to connect it through code then VpnManagementErrorStatus is other...

Comment: I'm stuck there too, because i can't set a PSK from code.

Comment: @andy my vpn is not connecting using username and password
and i think you connect the vpn using username and password...
i used the same code and connect vpn using username and password..
my protocol is ikev2 but vpn is not connecting and error is OTHER i don't know why this error comes

Comment: I have the save issue and there is no real documentation about using VPN from C#

Answer (score 4):

**VPN Native Profile** : This refers to a Windows Inbox / Built-In VPN profile and can be used for L2TP, PPTP or IKEv2 based VPN

**VPN Plugin Profile** : Refers to a Windows 10 UWP based VPN Plugin. This is a VPN app written using the Windows.networking.VPN namespace.

I also took a peek at the code and can see that there seems to be a very obvious miss where there isnt really a way to set the PSK via the code. The only real workaround would be to set it in the Settings UI for now.

I will go ahead and report to the VPN team for Windows about this being missing.

Documentation Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn

Comment: Thank you Aman Arneja. There is also the possibility to add a new VPN connection from xml string. Perhaps it would work this way, to set a PSK, but i can not find a complete sample of such an xml.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe there is also an outstanding issue with the AddProfileXMLAsync function. Have reported that to the team as well

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes with some testing i have found, that the status everytime is "AccessDenied".

Comment: Aman Arneja: It would be great if you could help us with this issue. There are more people that need sample codes for the UWP VPN feature, especially for the VPN Native Profile.

Comment: I do have some working samples, I can put them up in a git repo and share them soon. In the meantime is there a particular config you need help with ?

Comment: @AmanArneja-MSFT: Have you finished those samples? Yes, I still need some help from your side (if you are able to help me, I would appreciate it a lot)

Comment: I also need the config part, with which I can add the PSK.

Comment: Are there any news here? @AmanArneja-MSFT: Is it possible to share your working samples with us?

Comment: @AmanArneja-MSFT now four months are over and we have no samples, is it possible to share them?

Comment: @AmanArneja-MSFT another month is over, can you please provide your working samples to us? After the release of the april update 1803 from Microsoft, i still don't see any news regarding the API or the documentation on MSDN.

Comment: @AmanArneja-MSFTis there any news about fixed or samples? thanks!

Comment: It seems that those promised samples were not materialized